# mysql joining four table and count results order by desc

Tags: mysql

I'm working on Mysql to get the trending posts

I am joining four tables posts, posts_like, posts_shares, posts_comments and distinct the user_id of it. (post like, shares and comments should be added for total)

I am expecting a result of this for example only

```
RESULT:
post_id | user_id | count of shares, like, comments
---------------------------------------------------
  1     |     2    |      50                      |
  8     |     5    |      47                      |
---------------------------------------------------
```

table structure

```
table users
---------------------
id | username | etc |
---------------------

table posts
-------------------------------------
id |  user_id | content | datecreated
-------------------------------------

post_likes
--------------------------------
id | post_id | user_id         |
--------------------------------

post_shares
--------------------------------
id | post_id | user_id         |
--------------------------------

comments
---------------------------------------
id | post_id | user_id | description  |
--------------------------------------
```

user_id should be distinct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use left join and count distinct based  group by   p.id, p.user_id, u.username

```
select p.id as post_id, p.user_id, u.username
    , count(distinct l.user_id)
    , count(distinct s.user_id)
    , count(distinct c.user_id)
    , ifnull(count(distinct l.user_id),0) + 
      ifnull(count(distinct s.user_id),0) + 
      ifnull(count(distinct c.user_id),0) total
from post p 
inner join users u  on u.id = p.user_id 
left join post_likes l on l.post_id = p.id 
left join post_shares s on s.post_id = p.id  
left join comments c on c.post_id = p.id 
group by  p.id, p.user_id, u.username
order by total desc
```

Answer (score 0):

To get `count of shares, like, comments`, I suggest you to use `UNION` over these three tables.

Something like (check the syntax):

```
SELECT post_id, user_id, count(post_id) From (
SELECT post_id, user_id FROM post_likes
UNION
SELECT post_id, user_id FROM post_shares
UNION
SELECT post_id, user_id FROM comments) Group by post_id, user_id
```

Comment: that will return the total share, likes and comments? but wheres the sort to desc

Comment: i also don't see the table posts on that query

Comment: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias